# Customizing Regex for Validator in Python

Tags: python, regex, pyqt, validation

Just came across a line of code that enforces an user's text input into the dialog's field. Regardless of the input only IP format will be allowed at the end such as :

**123.456.789.100**

```
regexIP=QtCore.QRegExp("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
```

I would like to write a regex for lineedit validator that would automatically replace all the white spaces, commas, periods, dashes, minuses, dollar signs (everything except letters and number) with underscores.
I also would like to capitalize the first three letters and then insert an underscore right after them regardless of what the user types.

For instance, if an user types:

```
this is a beautiful day 77
```

the regex validator would automatically change it to:

```
THI_Sis_a_beatiful_day_77
```

Her is how PyQt portion of the code looks like:

```
my_regex = QtCore.QRegExp("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")

my_QLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

my_validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(my_regex, my_QLineEdit)

my_QLineEdit.setValidator( my_validator )
```

Once again, the code above is just an example. What I want is to write a regex expression to put it inside the brackets:

my_regex = QtCore.QRegExp(**my_regex_expression_goes_here**)

This my_regex expression would enforce that user never enters a white_space, period, comma, dollar sign into the text field (lineedit). Ideally I would like to capitalize first three letters and then put an underscore. But that is not a big deal any longer. Let's focus on how to achieve some basic regex expression so the user is not able to put white spaces, minus, dollar signs and etc. Only letters and numbers are allowed....

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Here's a RegEx you can use for the first part to match what you want: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+?`. Then just replace with `_`.

Comment: Are you sure that the result you want is not: `THI_s_is_a_beautiful_day_77` instead of what you have written?

Comment: Are consecutive non alphanumeric characters replaced with one or several underscores?

Comment: "...Are you sure that the result you want is not: THI_s_is_a_beautiful_day_77 instead of what you have written?..."   How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QRegExpValidator` class isn't really suitable for your use-case.

Instead, you should subclass `QValidator` and re-implement its [validate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html#validate) method to get the behaviour you want.

The script below provides a basic demo. It automatically uppercases the first three letters and inserts an underscore (if necessary). Also, all non-alphanumeric characters are automatically replaced with an underscore. If you want runs of non-alphanumeric characters replaced with a single underscore, add a "+" to the end of the regexp. Pasted text will also be automatically converted.

```
import sip, re
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Validator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Validator, self).__init__(parent)
        self._replace = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]').sub

    def validate(self, string, pos):
        string = self._replace('_', string)
        prefix = string[:3].upper()
        if len(string) > 3 and not string[3] == '_':
            prefix += '_'
            pos += 1
        string = prefix + string[3:]
        return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable, string, pos

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.validator = Validator(self)
        self.edit.setValidator(self.validator)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two replacements for this:

```
s = 'this is a beautiful day 77'
s = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', s)
s = re.sub('^.{3}', lambda match: match.group(0).upper() + '_', s)
```

Comment: I have to use regex in a syntax  similar to the example I posted: regexIP=QtCore.QRegExp("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")

Comment: Hi, Sputnix, I really don't understand.  If all you have is numbers (`\d` will *only* match digits), where does uppercasing enter into things?

Comment: This was just an example: regexIP=QtCore.QRegExp("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"). It has nothing to do with what I would like to achieve with my regex expression.